# Capture keyboard event

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple application to simulate a client movement in a restaurant.

When the app start in cmd, show a menu with an option to run the simulation.

I'm doing this using a math equation into a loop with an exact range (`For i in range(100)`) but I would like to do this using a while statement and stop just when the user presses a keyboard key (It does not matter which one).

But I'm not sure what library or module I need to use.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you considered using the Tkinter library?

Comment: not yet, I gonna test, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be most easiest to do in the `pygame` module, so I'd recommend that. If you don't have it already, do `pip install pygame` in your terminal.